# Why am I getting an error message when trying to plot an xts object in R?

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I am trying to plot an xts object in R. Below is the code I am running that gives me the error message.

```
outcomes_xts <- xts(true_outcomes, as.yearqtr(end_dates))

plot(as.zoo("outcomes_xts"),
     col = "purple",
     lwd = 4,
     ylab = "Quarterly Change in per-capita GDP (£)",
     main = paste0("ADL(1,1): Pseudo-Out-Of-Sample Forecasts of Differenced",
     " per-capita GDP, United Kingdom"),
     ylim = -200:200)
```

However this code gives me the following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

From what I gather, this can be caused by the data in the xts object being stored as character strings rather than numeric, but this isn't the case with this data. Neither is it caused by n/a's in the xts object - I have tried using na.omit() on the xts object but I still get the same error. Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is my result when I run `dput(outcomes_xts[1:30])`

```
structure(c(62, 48, 24, 30, 4, 12, 31, 58, 54, 70, 28, 13, 3, 
33, 46, 20, 37, 15, 31, -52, -131, -169, -149, -37, -10, 8, 37, 
69, 37, -6), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1057017600, 
1064966400, 1072915200, 1080777600, 1088640000, 1096588800, 1104537600, 
1112313600, 1120176000, 1128124800, 1136073600, 1143849600, 1151712000, 
1159660800, 1167609600, 1175385600, 1183248000, 1191196800, 1199145600, 
1207008000, 1214870400, 1222819200, 1230768000, 1238544000, 1246406400, 
1254355200, 1262304000, 1270080000, 1277942400, 1285891200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "yearqtr"), .Dim = c(30L, 
1L))
```

Comment: Hi. Can you add `dput(outcomes_xts)` to your question please. (you can subset it if the vector is too large ). Thanks

Comment: HI - please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help in making this reproducible in order to get help more quickly and accurately.

Comment: @user20650 done and added above, thanks

Comment: oops should of noticed: remove the quotations in `as.zoo(outcomes_xts)`

Comment: ps when you get errors it is worth looking at the individual components to try to find the source. So you could look at `as.zoo("outcomes_xts")` or `str(as.zoo("outcomes_xts"))` and see if it is what you expect (in this cse it os not)

Comment: @user20650 oh lol, thanks, daft moment from me